# how to blur animated SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, sprite-kit

I have loop, that generates animated Nodes (they moves across the screen) and I need to blur these nodes.
I have SKEffectNode with blur filter:

```
self.blur = [[SKEffectNode alloc] init];
[self.blur setShouldEnableEffects:YES];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
[self addChild:self.blur];
```

And then in loop I add into this SKEffectNode my animated SKSpriteNodes.

```
[self.blur addChild:gamePlatform];
```

Unfortunately, this works, but very slowly. Very! In fact, its ~2 FPS.
Are there any other solutions? Or how can I change this code to make it faster?
Or is this a problem of xCode's simulator I use?

Comment: Yup: ignore Simulator for performance. It's a software renderer.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator is responsible for the low frame rate.

Games tend to use way more cpu and ram than other apps. For that reason I recommend to always test your game on a real device and never in the simulator.

Hope that helps.